# Using Crystal Report Viewer in MVC4 with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

I want to show Crystal Reports from a previously generated Crystal Report templates `templatename.rpt` file.

I have also used it in MVC4 currently. But there are more requirement of Client for this Crystal Report that should be

1. Having Charts in Report with DrillDown.
2. Able to Download Report in different formats(.pdf,word,etc.)
          [Currently I am just giving option to download in PDF format].

I have looked through multiple examples & have done multiple searches for this found the solution in MVC3 with Visual Studio 2010. But that is not working perfectly in Visual Studio 2013 + MVC4